# C# Fire Webbrowser inside a method

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'm trying to write a code in C# which implements Brute-Force Attack to my temporary webpage in order to try crack the login system.
Something like this:

```
private void buttonHack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (!found)
        {
            textBox_pw.Text = guess;
            guesser.NextGuess();

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_id").SetAttribute("value", textBox_ID.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", textBox_pw.Text);
            webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:enter();");

            guess = new String(guesser.CurrentGuess);
        }
    }
```

// 'guess' and 'guesser' are for the BF Attack.

But apparently WebBrowser doesn't 'fire' until the method that it's called inside of returns. I have tried to put the part inside the while loop into the Webbrowser_DocumentCompleted event, so that it would literally loop (as when the page load is completed then do the same again and again...) But this way had its issues, like if the page document gets completed fast then it skips the rest of the code and goes to the top of DocumentCompleted method, and as the result weirdness!!!
So any neat ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Brute-Force attacks are not done by manipulating the web page itself, but rather by  generating traffic to the server that does the credential validation (unless of course you are  validating on the client in which case a simple javascript code review will suffice).

Code is written that mimics the webbroser control's interaction with the server (in order to tap into SSL-protected traffic).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do a loop like this because .Navigate is an async method.  You need to subscribe to the DocumentCompleted event on the brwoser control and do your work there.

Also, I'm unsure wheter .Navigate will take a javascipt: location.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that way several times, but that has its own cons..
And about javascripts, .Navigate does take 'em.